# Embedded systems linux project

Tags: embedded, filesystems, linux-kernel

I want to make a final year project for which i want a two way interface device. At one end it connects to a server and at the other it connects to an output display device for e.g. a television.

What are the requirements? And how do i do this?

Comment: You will probably need a television ... :)

Comment: thnaks that i know i serioulsy wants to know all the compenents and guide ...???

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this device:

[WD TV Digital AV player](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=wd+tv&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=310607017193719973&ei=Y2T0S8qcC6WINYGT5ZcF&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=image&resnum=2&ved=0CCcQ8gIwAQ#)

It has all of the capabilities you are describing (including embedded Linux), so researching it would be one way to build a list of requirements.